# Which statistical test to perform on non-parametric data with continuous (IV) and binary ( DV)

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I am working on to assess whether there is difference between the two variables, continuous (IV) and binary (DV) by using suitable statistical test. I actually started off by performing logistic regression on the data . However, I realised that the distribution of the data is not normal. So which test should I use?

Comment: What are the variables and what do you want to know? Do you have a null and and alternative hypothesis? How many observations?

Comment: IV: Annual income , DV= status of credit card default (0:No or 1:Yes) . I want to 
assess whether there is any difference between these two variables using statistical test.